# Calculating time differences in values from column A when the same corresponding value appears in column B

Tags: vba, excel

I get a report from my epos system that gives me a time in column A for the sale of a product and its barcode will appear in the corresponding column B. The same barcode will appear a second time in column B giving a later time in column A further down the list.

I'm trying to figure out how I can calculate the time difference between the values in column A between the first and second entry of that products barcode in column B. I know how to sum the values in column A based on criteria in column B using the IF function but can't figure out how to subtract.

Anybody any advice?

Comment: You can use VLOOKUP to locate a second entry, maybe coupled with COUNTIF() to avoid trying to calculate anything for later appearances.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following will point you in the right direction, if it doesn't do what you expect it to, the code will loop through column B to find matching codes and if it does it minuses the time values and enters the difference in column C (in hours format):

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To LastRow
valu = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
code = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
    For x = i + 1 To LastRow
        If ws.Cells(x, 2).Value = code Then
            s.Cells(i, 3).NumberFormat = "hh:mm"
            ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = (ws.Cells(x, 1).Value - valu)
        End If
    Next x
Next i
End Sub
```